# Count with SQL SubQuery in From Clause Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, scalar-subquery

I am trying to get the number of workdays over a range of dates and assign it to a variable and I can't seem to get it.  I have tried just my subquery and it works fine to get me the distinct dates but I need a count of them.  Here is the code that I wish would work:

```
 declare @end date='2016/05/06' 
 declare @begin date = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @end), 0) 
 declare @begin31 date = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @end)

 declare @tmprocdays int

  @tmprocdays = select count(*) from (select distinct WORKDATE from Daily where WORKDATE between @begin and @end)    <<<-----  NOT WORKING
```

The error says the problem is near the )   I've tried putting the while thing in parenthesis and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
declare @end date='2016/05/06' 
 declare @begin date = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @end), 0) 
 declare @begin31 date = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @end)

 declare @tmprocdays int

 set  @tmprocdays = select count(*) from (select distinct WORKDATE from Daily where WORKDATE between @begin and @end) a   <<<-----  NOT WORKING
```

**OR** Replace the last 2 lines above to this:

```
select @tmprocdays = count(*) 
from 
(
  select distinct WORKDATE from Daily where WORKDATE between @begin and @end
) a
```

**OR** even better

```
  select  @tmprocdays = count(distinct WORKDATE) from Daily where WORKDATE between @begin and @end
```

Comment: OMG -- I was on this for hours.  Thank you SO SO much!!!!  I didn't know you could put distinct in count.  Your last solution is very elegant.  Thank you.

Comment: @Missy you are most welcome ... just check the edits I added another alternative at the end which might work better.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the lack of parentheses around the subquery.

Here are some fixes to the code:

```
declare @end date = '2016-05-06';
declare @begin date = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @end), 0);
declare @begin31 date = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @end);

declare @tmprocdays int;

select @tmprocdays = count(distinct WORKDATE)
from Daily
where WORKDATE between @begin and @end ;
```

Changes:

- Put the `@tmprocdays =` in the `select` statement itself.  Your subquery is missing parentheses.
- Added semicolons to the end of each line.
- Removed the subquery, using `count(distinct)` instead.
- Changed the date to YYYY-MM-DD format.  This is at least an ISO standard.

The last three are cosmetic.

Answer (score 1):

The from clause must always contain either a table name, or in the case of a subquery it must be aliased:

If you add any identifier (word of letter) after your subquery it will work fine, eg:

```
@tmprocdays = select count(*) from (select distinct WORKDATE from Daily where WORKDATE between @begin and @end) xxx
```